# Facebook API is sending a GET request instead of a POST to my Chatbot

Tags: python, api, facebook, flask, request

When using Facebook Messenger to send a chat message to my Chatbot, I don't get a reply. Checking the server logs show that I am receiving a GET request whereas it should be a POST request.

This is weird because the chatbot works when tested by running the file locally, whereas upon deploying it on Digital Ocean Droplet, it receives it as a GET request.

The deployed version works if i explicitly send a POST request via Postman (while simulating a facebook messaging request body)

Is there any reason Facebook is sending / I am receiving it as a GET request instead of a POST?

I tried to test the file locally and it works, and through simulating requests with Postman. It just doesn't work if the request is sent via a message on Facebook Messenger

Comment: _"Checking the server logs show that I am receiving a GET request"_ - _just_ a GET request? Or a GET request as a follow-up to a POST request that got answered with a _redirect_ perhaps?

Comment: Just purely a GET request is shown

Comment: But the _verification_ part of the webhook setup was already handled correctly, yes?

Comment: Yes the verification has been set up and working. In fact if I send an explicit POST with Postman, it will allow my chatbot to respond to me on the messenger chat as well

Comment: There is no reason why Facebook should make a GET request then. And I still kinda rather doubt that they do - if there was a general error on their end, it would affect _all_ bots, and in that case we would probably have a lot more people here reporting issues right now. (Their bug tracker does also not appear to contain anything recent related to this.) More likely, that _something_ about your setup on Digital Ocean makes it go wrong. But if you think you can absolutely exclude that possibility, I'd file a bug report. https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/

Comment: Yes I'm also confused because I tested it on a local file before deploying to Digital Ocean and it works perfectly fine there. Any suggestions on what the setup could be affected that forces it to default to a GET?

Comment: Facebook is playing the part of the client here, they are initiating this request - so it is hard to imagine, that anything from your end _could_ somehow have forced it to make an initial GET request to begin with. Much more likely is that they made a POST request, but somehow it does not get handled correctly on the DO side. I don't know if Facebook would "follow" any redirects at this point (because that would not make much sense), perhaps it is some sort of "internal" request handling that makes it go wrong somehow.

Comment: Do you have any other hosting platform / server available, that you could deploy this to for testing purposes, to see if the problem occurs there as well?

Comment: No due to certain constraints, I dont have an alternative platform right now. I will look into seeing if somehow my code is making causing it to be a GET request or some internal handling that causes redirects. Any clue what may cause redirects to be GET?

Comment: I realise I may have been mistaken it could have been a redirect request as a follow-up to the POST request. Is there any reason for this? I have configured the endpoint to handle both GET and POST already...

Answer (score 0):

Made a mistake before, it was indeed related to the redirections as stated by CBroe.

POST Endpoint was made for url with a trailing slash whereas the callback set on facebook developers was set to handle no trailing slash. Just had to fix that and redirection issue was resolved!